# Help calculating an angle in a phasor diagram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I need help in order to find the angle $\delta$ in the phasor diagram seen in the picture

[image]

The magnitudes of $E_a$, $I_a$, $I_ajX_s$ and $I_aR_s$ are known, and in case it is not clear from the picture, the vectors $E_a$ and $I_ajX_s$ make a right angle.

Thanks in advance,

Edit:

Thank you for the feedback, and sorry if it seemed like I didn't even try, it's my first post here. Lets try that again.

Here is an updated picture including all your suggestions

[image: Phasor diagram 2].

Known quantities are: $e$, $y$, and $x$ and I have calculated $c$ as $c=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and the angle $\alpha$. I want to find out the value of $h$ in order to calculate $\delta$ using the sine. However, I'm stuck calculating $h$ as it seems I need another piece of information.

Any suggestions or tips and clues are appreciated as to how to proceed.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: This is not a "do my work for me " site. Please [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It is not clear where Ea ends and Ia starts. Also next time please use single lowercase letters for lengths.

Comment: This is not a question about math education, please, choose the tags carefully.

Comment: When asking a question here, please, simplify your notation. The names of those vectors looks unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your suggestions. I have updated the post with more clear questions and what I have done and what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a parallel to $x$ in the second figure, from the bottom right corner. Intersection with the $e$ line will be at $90^\circ$. So you have a right angle triangle, with one side $e-y$, and one side $x$. You can get $$v=\sqrt{(e-y)^2+x^2}$$ and $$\tan\delta=\frac{x}{e-y}$$

Comment: Thanks @Andrei ;)